# Changing the start up form in LWUIT

Tags: netbeans, java-me, lwuit

While the first time you generate a netbeans project from LWUIT (1.5) you are able to set a startup form, what about later on in the development when you decide to need to change it to another one instead. How do you change the start up form either in LWUIT resource editor or via code in netbeans? I wondered about regenerating the application, but I'm too scared of overwrites and app breakage at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the properties file in the root of the project to point at the new form name.